# Request Google Photos Permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-photos

I have an Image-Picker in my app.

- When I choose an image from Google Photos I have to save its URI
- Then I need to to show this image into an *ImageView* using this URI.
- I try to request Google Photo permission but it has no result.

`public static final String GOOGLE_PHOTOS_PERMISSION="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS";`

**Is it possible to get an image by URI from Google Photos?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082837/heard-of-com-google-android-apps-photos-permission-google-photos

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Uri` into `Bitmap` using this snippet:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

now set this `Bitmap` to `ImageView`.

Comment: The same result. Requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Library.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Use the Gradle File

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Check Picasso Library Documentation